# Is it possible to run Xcode 6.3 on El Capitan?

Tags: xcode, swift, osx-elcapitan

I'd really like to try El Capitan but I don't know if it is possible to run old Xcode on it, because it is critical for me now. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I'm 99.9% sure that it'd work, Apps don't just stop working on a newer version, especially on Macs

Comment: It will probably work, but I'd be careful about installing a beta OS on my production system. Get an external hard drive and install El Capitan there.

Comment: The latest el capitan patch broke Xcode 6.4 + 6.3, so follow these steps to run it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040744/xcode-6-3-2-cant-run-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan-developer-preview-2

Comment: You can check the steps to put to work Xcode on this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220697/xcode-6-4-on-osx-10-11-beta-2-beta-3-el-capitan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xCode 6.3.2 does run on the first El Capitan beta. I have tried building and running a swift app, this worked just like it should.

Although using xCode 6.3.2 does work on the first (and second) El Capitan beta. There might be some extra steps involved.

**Submissions to the App Store will be rejected!** if you are using a beta version of OSX

Comment: Wont work on Beta 2, beware to update if you want to use Xcode 6 in El Capitan.

Comment: it's too late for a warning. how do I continue my work?

Comment: I just do "open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode" in a terminal window

Comment: Just be aware you can't submit anything to App Store if you are running El Capitan beta, regardless of the version of Xcode

Comment: For those trying to get it to work with preview 2, this will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040744/xcode-6-3-2-cant-run-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan-developer-preview-2

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald source for that? iTC seems to complain about the Xcode version, doesn't mention OS version...

Comment: I tried submitting with the correct version of Xcode 6.3.2 on the previous El Capitan beta and got rejected.

Comment: @duncan What was the reason of rejection? Was it in regards to being on El Capitan?

Comment: @milo526 it was a message saying you can't submit from this version of the OS.

Answer (score 9):

Run this command on Terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode /dev/null
```