# Xcode 6.3.2 can't run on OSX 10.11 El Capitan Developer Preview 3

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan

I'm just updated my Mac to OS X 10.11 El Capitan DP 2, and I disappointed that it does not support Xcode 6.3.2

Now, how do I work? I have a project to do, and it's not a good time to convert my project to Swift 2/Xcode 7 since it's impossible to submitting at this time?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to MacOS 10.10 on a separate partition on your hard drive.  In my own set-up, I have a few different partitions... some for previous MacOS versions (10.8, 10.9), one for the most up-to-date-official, and one for a Developer Preview release.

Comment: You can see how to put to work on this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220697/xcode-6-4-on-osx-10-11-beta-2-beta-3-el-capitan

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Open terminal and use this command

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

Comment: Thank you, does this way helps run Xcode normally? My friend tried this but he said it made some crashes when create a new files

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly help. Redirecting stdin and stdout isn't going to magically make an application compatible with a different OS.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: It does seem to work according to Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6653#15226

Comment: @AndrewMedico Without actually having had a look at it, my wild guess is that it's not about stdin/stdout/stderr, but about the fact that it's run from the Terminal. Most likely XCode 6.3.2 is perfectly compatible with OS X 10.11, but Apple blocked it per some UI restriction by which the Terminal is not affected. The pipe redirection is only to properly detach the process (not sure what would otherwise happen if you closed the Terminal window with XCode still running).

Answer (score 3):

From the [El Capitan release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/):

> Xcode versions prior to 7 are not supported on OS X El Capitan Beta 3

And from the [Xcode 7 beta 4 release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_4/Xcode_7_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf):

> Xcode 6.x has known compatibility issues when run on OS X version 10.11 El Capitan. It is strongly encouraged that you use Xcode 7 when running on OS X El Capitan.

I know it doesn't help you much now, but as a general rule of thumb, I recommend not upgrading *anything* in your build process if you're on a deadline and you can't easily revert.

Comment: Previous version are not supported but they works.  I have working xcode 6.4 on El Capitan beta 3.

Comment: Added a comment from the Xcode 7 beta 4 release notes to my answer. They strongly recommend that you not use 6.x on 10.11.