# Xcode 6.4 on OSX 10.11 (El Capitan) beta 2 / beta 3

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to run Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan and I can run with the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040744/xcode-6-3-2-cant-run-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan-developer-preview-2) post.

But I am looking for a way to run it without any external program as I ran before with OSX 10.10 (Yosemite).

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/3awe5u/warning_xcode_6_el_capitan_beta_2/) post that point to [this](http://pastebin.com/K2AKuWL9) instructions but it does not work.  These are the instructions

> 1. Open this file /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exception.plist
> 2. Find lines with name xcode in them (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEAbB.png)
> 3. Edit value HardDisabled from YES to NO
> 4. Save and reboot
>
>    1.a) If you can't save because file says it's locked then enable
>      rootless mode (sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless 0" or
>      sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1 rootless=0") and reboot.
>
>    1.b) If you still have problem, copy Exceptions.plist to Desktop (or
>      wherever else) and edit it them.
>
>    1.c) Save it and them remove
>      Exceptions.plist in System (sudo rm -rf
>      /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist)
>
>    1.d) Copy file from Desktop (or wherever else) to
>      /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources and
>      reboot.

I couldn't edit the Exceptions.plist file with the instructions above, but after a lot of tries I found the way to edit it.
 [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/936123/edit-exceptions-plist-on-osx-10-11-beta-2-el-capitan/936269#936269) you can find the instructions to edit it.

After all of this, I still receiving the message

> You can't open the application "XCode.app" because it is not supported
>   on this type of Mac

when I try to run Xcode 6.4 from Finder

**SOLUTION 1**
The only thing I didn't do was to reinstall XCode 6.4 after the changes.  I reinstalled it and it works!

**SOLUTION 2**
[Dave Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144857/dave-wood) provided another solution to avoid to reinstall XCode.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31310418/3761982) is is post and as he posted in his answer the script is [here](http://bit.ly/Xcode6OnElCapitan)

Comment: Why would you use a beta version of OS X, but not a beta version of Xcode?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen has a good point. If you're going to be writing code on a beta version of OS X, why not just go whole hog and use the beta version of Xcode which actually runs on the OS without any hacks or modifications?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen because I have a project I am working on and I don't want to switch that project to Swift 2.0 yet.

Comment: @CrApHeR Then you really shouldn't be using a OS X beta version... That's the whole idea with it.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I upgraded to 10.11 because I want to try XCode 7 but specifically for that project I want to keep it on XCode 6.

Comment: @CrApHeR Xcode 7 works fine on Yosemite. I run both 6 and 7 (beta) in parallel.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen XCode 6.4 is working on El Capitan.  I updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 6.4 runs out-of-the-box on:

- El Capitan Beta 4 (build 15A226f)
- El Capitan Beta 5 (build 15A235d)
- El Capitan Beta 7 (build 15A263e)

Xcode 6.4 fails to open on:

- El Capitan Beta 6 (build 15A244d) - Workaround [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/36684#36684)

  ```
  cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
  sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
  ```

Comment: Beta 6 seems to break Xcode 6 and 7 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170

Comment: Solution was found. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places in Exceptions.plist which list Xcode. The one you don't have listed is:

```
<key>com.apple.Xcode</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>AppStoreIdentifier</key>
            <string>497799835</string>
            <key>AppStoreUpdateIsFree</key>
            <true/>
            <key>HardDisabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>HighVersion</key>
            <string>5085.0</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

It is necessary to re-install Xcode afterwards.

Comment: You are right, I didn't mention but I modified both places switching HardDisabled to NO.  (I edited the binary plist with XCode-beta).

Comment: And you've verified the Exceptions.plist currently in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/… has the correct changes? Not sure what to say. I also disabled rootless and made only those changes earlier than the date of that post, from instructions I found that applied to Xcode and Yosemite beta, in attempting to get Xcode 6.3.1 to work. It didn't work, but then after upgrading to 6.4, it did and I thought perhaps Xcode 6.4 was made to work with 10.11 beta 2. I would guess that's a runtime check, and myself having made that change before installing 6.4 doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I verified the file Exceptions.plist on that folder and the changes are there. (I verified both places).  Maybe the solution is to reinstall XCode 6.4 after the changes.

Comment: Possible. I'm hesitant to try anything since it works on my machine. But I can confirm that I made only the same changes you did, and the only difference was I made them before installing Xcode 6.4. For editing the file, I used BBEdit, which didn't require moving or changing permissions. btw, when you say HardDisabled to 'NO', you mean "<false/>", correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. if you edit the binary plist in XCode, it appears as NO, but it is false in the "non-binary" version.

Comment: It works! I reinstalled Xcode 6.4 and it works perfectly! :)

Comment: excellent. I've updated my answer to say it requires re-installation. There's also possibly some extended attribute one could remove with 'xattr -d …' that wold make it easier and not require re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the original first answer if you dont want to reinstall xcode again because of slow internet connection you can just copy xcode to desktop delete the one in application folder (Assuming you did all the required steps above except reinstalling). And move back xcode to application folder(while copying to desktop itself if you did above step right you will notice the cut icon will dissapear after copying)

Answer (score 0):

User lembacon [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/36684#36684) found the solution:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
cd Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

> The reason is that the internal implementation of
>   `_NSGetExecutablePath` has been updated (where the Kernel is
>   involved), and the host `dyld` has also been updated to track this
>   change. The `dyld_sim`, however, has not yet been updated. So the
>   problem is that `_NSGetExecutablePath` will return a path that
>   contains a `executable_path=` part which causes  that the
>   `CFBundleGetMainBundle()` always returns `NULL`. This workaround
>   simply forces the simulator to use the host `dyld`.

I confirm that this solution is working with Xcode 6.4.