# Xcode 6.1.1 in El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode6, osx-elcapitan

Is it possible to run Xcode 6.1.1 in El Capitan?

Reference Links

[For Xcode 6.3 not for 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827580/is-it-possible-to-run-xcode-6-3-on-el-capitan)

Answer (score 0):

I think no because **Command Line Tools for Xcode 6.1.1** available only for **OS X Yosemite (10.10)**. So you can try it. For more info you can read from this link https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: I want for xcode 6.1.1 all results that i searched are for xcode 6.3 and 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Open terminal and run:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode 8.2.1 and its the latest version for el-capitan.

> need 5Gb downloads